# $A$ is a nonsingular square matrix, does it imply $A^TA$ is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is a $n\times n$ nonsingular real matrix, does it imply $A^TA$ is positive definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you prefer the $\langle .,.\rangle$ notation for inner products, this is because $$\langle x, A^TA x\rangle = \langle Ax, Ax\rangle$$

by definition.

Or, if you prefer the $.^T .$ notation, it's because

$$x^T(A^TAx) = (x^TA^T)(Ax) = (Ax)^T Ax$$

and this is only equal to $0$ if $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

One well-known result is the following:

> **Theorem.** $X$ is nonnegative definite if and only if there is a square matrix $B$ such that $X = BB^{T}$.

Since $A^{T}$ is square, it follows that $A^{T}A$ must be nonnegative definite.

> **Corollary**. $X = BB^{T}$ is positive definite if and only if $B$ is invertible for any $B$.

To see why this is true, approach this as a proof by contrapositive. Suppose $B$ is noninvertible. Then this is true if and only if there is a $v \neq 0$ (a column vector) such that $B^{T}v = 0$, or $v^{T}BB^{T}v = 0$. With $X = BB^{T}$, $v^{T}Xv = 0$. Equivalently, $X = BB^{T}$ satisfies $v^{T}Xv \neq 0$ if and only if $B$ is invertible, and because of the $BB^{T}$ factorization, it follows that $X$ must be positive definite.